# Gridview templatefields databind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, templatefield

I have a gridview with the following code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column1">     
    <EditItemTemplate>         
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Column1") %>'></asp:Label  
    </EditItemTemplate>     
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="125px">         
    </asp:DropDownList>     
    </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to bind a sql statement to populate the dropdownlist...

select Column1 from Table1 would I do this through the code behind?

Comment: you can use the gridview_ItemDataBound Event to popupate the dropdownlist control

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the codebehind if you wish, or, if it applies to your situation, you can use the ObjectDataSource web server control.

More reading: [ObjectDataSource Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx)

Here's an example on how to bind the ObjectDataSource to your dropdown: [asp.net ObjectDataSource example: how to populate DropDownList](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/12/aspnet-objectdatasource-example-how-to_8285.html)